# OSX installing vim via brew for python3

Tags: python, vim, homebrew

i want to install vim via brew for python3, but it always failure. 
below is the log:

```
LiuJustins-MacBook-Pro:~ justin$ brew install vim --without-python --with-python3
==> Downloading https://github.com/vim/vim/archive/v8.0.1400.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/justin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/vim-8.0.1400.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.1400_4/share
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/justin/Library/Logs/Homebrew/vim/02.make:
CF_EXPORT const CFCalendarIdentifier kCFISO8601Calendar API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.6), ios(4.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0));
                                                       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFLocale.h:197:63: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
CF_EXPORT const CFCalendarIdentifier kCFIslamicTabularCalendar API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.10), ios(8.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0));
                                                              ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFLocale.h:198:65: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
CF_EXPORT const CFCalendarIdentifier kCFIslamicUmmAlQuraCalendar API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.10), ios(8.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0));
                                                                ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [objects/os_mac_conv.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
20 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [objects/os_macosx.o] Error 1
make: *** [first] Error 2
```

READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting.html

```
Error: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.
```

Comment: Don't use images for codes/messages. Post them here instead.

Comment: i've attached the message.

Comment: So, did you try updating your command-line tools like the error said? By App Store upgrade of XCode; `xcode-select --install`

Comment: yes, i've already run xcode-select --install as below: LiuJustins-MacBook-Pro:Homebrew justin$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: And, did you do _that_? Software Update? Via App Store?

Comment: i've checked in App store, there is no software update.

Answer (score -2):

Solution: Manually download the install package ("Command Line Tools for Xcode.dwg") from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/, and rerun the command "brew install vim --without-python --with-python3". Now it works.

Comment: vim: this formula has no --with-python3 option